# Can I open two websites on one hyperlink?

Tags: html

I want to open two different websites on one hyperlink mean one click.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to open two urls in one link? Opening one url in current window/tab and another url in a new window/tab might be a bit annoying for the visitors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
 function DoubleOpen(site1, site2) { 
 window.open(site1); 
 window.location = site2; 
 } 
</SCRIPT>
```

From [here](http://forum.codecall.net/javascript/2000-javascript-opening-2-links-1-click.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="primaryPage.html" onclick="loadSecondary('secondaryPage.html);">Go Here</a>

<script>
  function loadSecondary(url) {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
      return true;
    }
</script>
```